# failed to link example program using id3 library

Tags: c++, hyperlink, id3, id3-tag, id3lib

i am trying to use [lib id3](http://id3lib.sourceforge.net/) to access mp3 tags with the ultimate aim of accessing album art from mp3 music files.

The problem is that i have even failed to compile the example programs that come with the id3 library.
problem 1.
trying to compile an example program in my project first generates this error

```
1>*** NOTICE *** (not a real error)
1>* You should include a define in your project which reflect how you link the library
1>* If you use id3lib.lib or libprj/id3lib.dsp (you link static) you should add
1>* ID3LIB_LINKOPTION=1 to your preprocessor definitions of your project.
1>* If you use id3lib.dll (you link dynamic) you should add ID3LIB_LINKOPTION=3
1>* to your preprocessor definitions of your project.
```

when i try to add

```
#define ID3LIB_LINKOPTION 1
```

to my source file , i get many more errors.

```
1>Linking...
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::setstate(int,bool)" (?setstate@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXH_N@Z) already defined in id3lib.lib(tag_parse.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sputn(char const *,int)" (?sputn@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEHPBDH@Z) already defined in id3lib.lib(tag_file.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: static bool __cdecl std::char_traits<char>::eq_int_type(int const &,int const &)" (?eq_int_type@?$char_traits@D@std@@SA_NABH0@Z) already defined in id3lib.lib(tag_parse.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: static int __cdecl std::char_traits<char>::eof(void)" (?eof@?$char_traits@D@std@@SAHXZ) already defined in id3lib.lib(tag_parse.obj)
```

From these errors i assume that the cause of the problems is id3lib.lib in the additional dependencies. But even if i remove it from the dependencies i still get these errors

```
1>Linking...
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall ID3_Tag::~ID3_Tag(void)" (??1ID3_Tag@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class ID3_Field & __thiscall ID3_Frame::Field(enum ID3_FieldID)const " (?Field@ID3_Frame@@QBEAAVID3_Field@@W4ID3_FieldID@@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall ID3_Frame::Contains(enum ID3_FieldID)const " (?Contains@ID3_Frame@@QBE_NW4ID3_FieldID@@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class ID3_Frame * __thiscall ID3_Tag::Find(enum ID3_FrameID)const " (?Find@ID3_Tag@@QBEPAVID3_Frame@@W4ID3_FrameID@@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall ID3_Tag::ID3_Tag(char const *)" (??0ID3_Tag@@QAE@PBD@Z) referenced in function _main
1>C:\Users\GuestUser\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\idlib example\Debug\idlib example.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals
```

Please help me. Am beginning to feel like a c++ newbie :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't link in msvcprtd.lib  which is a default library already included in the id3lib.lib.

You definitely want to link in id3lib.lib

Comment: i don't understand, i explicitly linked to id3lib.lib but i never personally linked to msvcprtd.lib. I don't know how it is comming in. Please clarify

Comment: ave given up :(. am trying taglib

Comment: its a default library automatically linked in. there is a link option to exclude it.